# Avoiding memory corruption in ClientDataSets with poPropagateChanges and poFetchDetailsOnDemand?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tclientdataset

Apologies in advance for a rather large reduced program to show the problem... Full code at the end of my question.

I've got a program using `TClientDataSet` extensively, sometimes leading to error messages for what as far as I can tell is correct code. I've reduced this to a sample program that runs on a `.\SQLEXPRESS` MSSQL instance, on the `tempdb` database, and uses `TClientDataSet` to access three tables with master-detail links. The database structure looks like this:

```
╔═══════════╗    ╔═══════════╗    ╔═══════════╗
║ Test1     ║    ║ Test2     ║    ║ Test3     ║
╟───────────╢    ╟───────────╢    ╟───────────╢
║ id        ║─┐  ║ id        ║─┐  ║ id        ║
║ datafield ║ └──║ Test1     ║ └──║ Test2     ║
╚═══════════╝    ║ datafield ║    ║ datafield ║
                 ╚═══════════╝    ╚═══════════╝
```

In this simplified version, the three `id` fields are simple integer fields, but in my real code, they are identity columns. This is not directly relevant, except for the invariable "why are you doing this?" question.

When pushing a record into `Test3`, in the provider's `BeforeUpdateRecord` event, I set its `Test2` value to the corresponding record's `id` field. This is necessary, as it does not happen automatically when a real identity column is used and the `Test2` record is newly inserted. I also use `NewValue` for other server-calculated values.

After I've called `ApplyUpdates`, which succeeds, I attempt to fetch the detail records for the next master record. This succeeds, the details get loaded, *but*: the detail record is marked as `usModified`, even though the data set's `ChangeCount` is zero. In other words, the last assert fails.

Delphi 2010 behaves the same, and comes with MIDAS sources, allowing me to trace to figure out what's going wrong. In short, `OverWriteRecord` is used when pushing the `NewValue` back into the database. `OverWriteRecord` uses record `iRecNoNext` as a temporary buffer, and leaves its `attr` field trashed. FetchDetails later ends up calling `InsertRecord`, which assumes the new record buffer's `attr` is still 0. It isn't 0, and everything goes wrong after that.

Knowing that, I could solve it by changing the MIDAS sources to always reset `attr`. Except Delphi XE Pro doesn't include them. So, my questions:

- Is this problem fixed in Delphi XE3?

  - If so, is its `midas.dll` freely redistributable?

    - If so, where can I get it?
- If not, is there any way to avoid the problem *without* changing the MIDAS sources?

Note that having the problem occur less frequently (by avoiding setting `NewValue` except when strictly necessary) is insufficient.

Both the use of `poPropagateChanges` to move the `NewValue`s back into the original ClientDataSet, and the use of `poFetchDetailsOnDemand` to not load all detail records in one go, are essential to the application.

*New observation*: the code in `InsertRecord` (in `dsupd.cpp`):

```
if (!bDisableLog) // Nov. -97
{
    piAttr[iRecNoNext-1] = dsRecNew;
}
```

intentionally does not clear the attribute. When it is called from `ReadRows` (in `dsinmem2.cpp`), the attribute gets set before `InsertRecord` gets called, so resetting the attribute in that case would be wrong. Whatever would need to be changed shouldn't be changed at that point anyway.

Full code:

**DBClientTest.dpr**:

```
program DBClientTest;

uses
  Forms,
  MainForm in 'MainForm.pas' {frmMain};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**MainForm.dfm**:

```
object frmMain: TfrmMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'frmMain'
  ClientHeight = 297
  ClientWidth = 297
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ADOConnection: TADOConnection
    Connected = True
    ConnectionString =
      'Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security I' +
      'nfo=False;User ID="";Initial Catalog=tempdb;Data Source=.\SQLEXP' +
      'RESS;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=SSPI'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Provider = 'SQLNCLI10.1'
    Left = 32
    Top = 8
  end
  object DropTablesCommand: TADOCommand
    CommandText =
      'if object_id('#39'Test3'#39') is not null'#13#10#9'drop table Test3;'#13#10#13#10'if obje' +
      'ct_id('#39'Test2'#39') is not null'#13#10#9'drop table Test2;'#13#10#13#10'if object_id('#39 +
      'Test1'#39') is not null'#13#10#9'drop table Test1;'
    Connection = ADOConnection
    ExecuteOptions = [eoExecuteNoRecords]
    Parameters = <>
    Left = 32
    Top = 56
  end
  object CreateTablesCommand: TADOCommand
    CommandText =
      'create table Test1 ('#13#10#9'id int not null identity(1, 1) primary ke' +
      'y,'#13#10#9'datafield int not null );'#13#10#13#10'create table Test2 ('#13#10#9'id int ' +
      'not null identity(1, 1) primary key,'#13#10#9'Test1 int not null'#13#10#9#9'con' +
      'straint FK_Test2_Test1 foreign key references Test1 ( id ),'#13#10#9'da' +
      'tafield int not null );'#13#10#13#10'create table Test3 ('#13#10#9'id int not nul' +
      'l identity(1, 1) primary key,'#13#10#9'Test2 int not null'#13#10#9#9'constraint' +
      ' FK_Test3_Test2 foreign key references Test2 ( id ),'#13#10#9'datafield' +
      ' int not null );'
    Connection = ADOConnection
    ExecuteOptions = [eoExecuteNoRecords]
    Parameters = <>
    Left = 32
    Top = 104
  end
  object Test1ADO: TADODataSet
    Connection = ADOConnection
    CursorType = ctStatic
    CommandText = 'select id, datafield from Test1;'
    IndexFieldNames = 'id'
    Parameters = <>
    Left = 32
    Top = 152
    object Test1ADOid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test1ADOdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
  end
  object Test2ADO: TADODataSet
    Connection = ADOConnection
    CursorType = ctStatic
    CommandText = 'select id, Test1, datafield from Test2 where Test1 = :id;'
    DataSource = Test1ADODS
    IndexFieldNames = 'Test1;id'
    MasterFields = 'id'
    Parameters = <
      item
        Name = 'id'
        Attributes = [paSigned]
        DataType = ftInteger
        Precision = 10
        Value = 1
      end>
    Left = 32
    Top = 200
    object Test2ADOid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test2ADOTest1: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Test1'
    end
    object Test2ADOdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
  end
  object Test3ADO: TADODataSet
    Connection = ADOConnection
    CursorType = ctStatic
    CommandText = 'select id, Test2, datafield from Test3 where Test2 = :id;'
    DataSource = Test2ADODS
    IndexFieldNames = 'Test2;id'
    MasterFields = 'id'
    Parameters = <
      item
        Name = 'id'
        Attributes = [paSigned]
        DataType = ftInteger
        Precision = 10
        Value = 1
      end>
    Left = 32
    Top = 248
    object Test3ADOid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test3ADOTest2: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Test2'
    end
    object Test3ADOdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
  end
  object Test1ADODS: TDataSource
    DataSet = Test1ADO
    Left = 104
    Top = 152
  end
  object Test2ADODS: TDataSource
    DataSet = Test2ADO
    Left = 104
    Top = 200
  end
  object DataSetProvider: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = Test1ADO
    Options = [poFetchDetailsOnDemand, poPropogateChanges, poUseQuoteChar]
    BeforeUpdateRecord = DataSetProviderBeforeUpdateRecord
    Left = 184
    Top = 152
  end
  object Test1CDS: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    FetchOnDemand = False
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider'
    Left = 256
    Top = 152
    object Test1CDSid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test1CDSdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
    object Test1CDSTest2ADO: TDataSetField
      FieldName = 'Test2ADO'
    end
  end
  object Test2CDS: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    DataSetField = Test1CDSTest2ADO
    FetchOnDemand = False
    Params = <>
    Left = 256
    Top = 200
    object Test2CDSid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test2CDSTest1: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Test1'
    end
    object Test2CDSdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
    object Test2CDSTest3ADO: TDataSetField
      FieldName = 'Test3ADO'
    end
  end
  object Test3CDS: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    DataSetField = Test2CDSTest3ADO
    FetchOnDemand = False
    Params = <>
    Left = 256
    Top = 248
    object Test3CDSid: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'id'
      ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
    end
    object Test3CDSTest2: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Test2'
    end
    object Test3CDSdatafield: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'datafield'
    end
  end
end
```

**MainForm.pas**:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, DB, ADODB, DBClient, Provider;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection: TADOConnection;
    DropTablesCommand: TADOCommand;
    CreateTablesCommand: TADOCommand;
    Test1ADO: TADODataSet;
    Test1ADOid: TIntegerField;
    Test1ADOdatafield: TIntegerField;
    Test2ADO: TADODataSet;
    Test2ADOid: TIntegerField;
    Test2ADOTest1: TIntegerField;
    Test2ADOdatafield: TIntegerField;
    Test3ADO: TADODataSet;
    Test3ADOid: TIntegerField;
    Test3ADOTest2: TIntegerField;
    Test3ADOdatafield: TIntegerField;
    Test1ADODS: TDataSource;
    Test2ADODS: TDataSource;
    DataSetProvider: TDataSetProvider;
    Test1CDS: TClientDataSet;
    Test1CDSid: TIntegerField;
    Test1CDSdatafield: TIntegerField;
    Test1CDSTest2ADO: TDataSetField;
    Test2CDS: TClientDataSet;
    Test2CDSid: TIntegerField;
    Test2CDSTest1: TIntegerField;
    Test2CDSdatafield: TIntegerField;
    Test2CDSTest3ADO: TDataSetField;
    Test3CDS: TClientDataSet;
    Test3CDSid: TIntegerField;
    Test3CDSTest2: TIntegerField;
    Test3CDSdatafield: TIntegerField;
    procedure DataSetProviderBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
      SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet;
      UpdateKind: TUpdateKind; var Applied: Boolean);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmMain }

procedure TfrmMain.DataSetProviderBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
  SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind: TUpdateKind;
  var Applied: Boolean);
begin
  if SourceDS = Test3ADO then
  begin
    with DeltaDS.FieldByName(Test3CDSTest2.FieldName) do
      NewValue := DeltaDS.DataSetField.DataSet.FieldByName(Test2CDSid.FieldName).Value;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DropTablesCommand.Execute;
  try
    CreateTablesCommand.Execute;

    Test1ADO.Open;
    Test2ADO.Open;
    Test3ADO.Open;

    Assert(Test1ADO.IsEmpty);
    Test1ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, 1 ]);

      Assert(Test2ADO.IsEmpty);
      Test2ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, Test1ADOid.Value, 2 ]);

        Assert(Test3ADO.IsEmpty);
        Test3ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, Test2ADOid.Value, 3 ]);

    Test1ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, 4 ]);

      Assert(Test2ADO.IsEmpty);
      Test2ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, Test1ADOid.Value, 5 ]);

        Assert(Test3ADO.IsEmpty);
        Test3ADO.AppendRecord([ nil, Test2ADOid.Value, 6 ]);

    Test3ADO.Close;
    Test2ADO.Close;
    Test1ADO.Close;

    Test1CDS.Open;

    Test1CDS.First;
    Assert(Test1CDSdatafield.Value = 1);

    Assert(Test2CDS.IsEmpty);
    Test1CDS.FetchDetails;
    Assert(Test2CDS.RecordCount = 1);

    Assert(Test3CDS.IsEmpty);
    Test2CDS.FetchDetails;
    Assert(Test3CDS.RecordCount = 1);

    Test3CDS.First;
    Assert(Test3CDSdatafield.Value = 3);
    Test3CDS.Edit;
    Test3CDSdatafield.Value := -3;
    Test3CDS.Post;

    Test1CDS.ApplyUpdates(0);

    Assert(Test3CDSdatafield.Value = -3);

    Test1CDS.Last;
    Assert(Test1CDSdatafield.Value = 4);

    Assert(Test2CDS.IsEmpty);
    Test1CDS.FetchDetails;
    Assert(Test2CDS.RecordCount = 1);
    Assert(Test2CDS.UpdateStatus = usUnmodified);

    Assert(Test3CDS.IsEmpty);
    Test2CDS.FetchDetails;
    Assert(Test3CDS.RecordCount = 1);
    Assert(Test3CDS.UpdateStatus = usUnmodified);
  finally
    DropTablesCommand.Execute;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Check the answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210025/how-to-mark-all-tclientdataset-records-as-inserted). I think it might help you to solve it without having to modify the midas source.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. I have my doubts about it, as the midas layer will in various places check the attribute directly without reading the CDS's buffer, but I'll certainly give it a try.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Unfortunately, as I feared, that does not work. Attempting to fake the attribute as unmodified does give UpdateStatus usUnmodified, but then modifying the record results in an unexpected exception "Operation not applicable".

Comment: I found old references to this problem like in this [link](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/2b/458104.html). It seems it is an error that happens since D5 but should have been fixed in [QC#2333](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2333) a long time ago. You could try the suggested workarounds in the report. Hope that helps...

Comment: @GuillemVicens That's a different bug. `ChangeCount` is 0 in my case, so `MergeChangeLog` doesn't do anything.

Comment: sorry, should have read it more carefully. I am out of ideas except for suggesting contacting Embarcadero's technical support or file a QC :-/

Comment: @GuillemVicens Their tech support requires a support contract (which makes sense), which I do not have, but is an option that I will consider. QC gives me the impression that I will be lucky if it gets fixed some time after 2020, but I will report it there (later) anyway if someone can confirm that XE3 still has this problem. Thanks for the extra search, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive searching through the D2010 MIDAS code, I have determined that for the uses in my application, there are three possibilities for `InsertRecord`:

- The attribute is already set to 0
- The attribute is not set and will not be set
- The attribute needs to be set to `dsRecNew`

The fourth possibility, the attribute having already been set to a value other than 0, is not one that can occur in my application. Because of that, always setting the attribute at that point is not a problem for me. I am taking a slight gamble and saying that this is still true with XE's MIDAS DLL.

I opted for manually loading MIDAS.DLL, and patching it in-memory. Based on the D2010 code:

```
if (!bDisableLog) // Nov. -97
{
    piAttr[iRecNoNext-1] = dsRecNew;
}
```

compiles to

```
837B2400   cmp dword ptr [ebx+$24],$00
750B       jnz skip
8B4338     mov eax,[ebx+$38]
8B537C     mov edx,[ebx+$7c]
C64410FF04 mov byte ptr [edx+eax-$01],$04
           skip:
```

Knowing that `bDisableLog` is either 0 or 1, I've changed the code to the effect of

```
piAttr[iRecNoNext-1] = (bDisableLog - 1) & dsRecNew;
```

which can be compiled to

```
8B4324     mov eax,[ebx+$24]
48         dec eax
83E004     and eax,$04
8B5338     mov edx,[ebx+$38]
8B737C     mov esi,[ebx+$7c]
884432FF   mov [edx+esi-$01],al
```

which is the exact same number of bytes. `esi` did not hold a value that needed to be preserved.

So in my code:

- I call `LoadLibrary('midas.dll')`
- I call `GetProcAddress(handle, 'DllGetClassObject')`
- I have found that the code above is `$24094` bytes after `DllGetClassObject`
- I verify that reading 17 bytes produces the 17 expected bytes
- I call `VirtualProtect` to ensure the memory is writable (copy on write, to be exact)
- I overwrite the memory
- I call `VirtualProtect` again to restore the memory protection
- Finally, I pass the address of `DllGetClassObject` to `RegisterMidasLib`, to prevent `DBClient` from attempting to load MIDAS.DLL again, or perhaps even a different MIDAS.DLL

Yes, this is fragile and will break with newer versions of MIDAS.DLL. If that turns out to be a problem, I can ensure that XE's MIDAS.DLL gets loaded from the application directory, bypassing any MIDAS that happens to be installed system-wide. If/when I upgrade to a newer version of Delphi, regardless of whether this bug will have been fixed, I will make sure it is a version that includes the MIDAS sources, so that I can avoid getting stuck on problems like this.